# Pulling a CSV file with python where cookie based authentication is used

Tags: python, cookies, openwrt

I use gargoyle router which has a bandwidth.csv file with details of all the machines attached to it.

To access the bandwidth.csv file a login in required, and as far as I can tell, a cookie is stored upon login, then the file can be downloaded.

```
# Read CSV File
url='http://mygargoylerouter/utility/get_password_cookie.sh'
s =requests.session()
p = dict(postparms = 'mygargoylepassword')
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
r = s.post(url,params = p,headers=headers)
print r
print r.text
c = r.cookies
r = requests.get('http://mygargoylerouter/bandwidth.csv', cookies = c, verify = False)
```

Here's the code I have, but it seems to pull back a page...and I can't even tell if I'm logged in on not.

The print r, returns a 200

Comment: Have you tried using the built-in authentication methods from the Requests module? Not sure how your router requires the authentication details, but have a look at [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/). Hope it helps!

Comment: No sure if uses any of those.  I have code similar in c# which goes and gets cookies from the special page get_password_cookie after passing it the parm password=mygargolepassword.